# JavaScript Rich Text Editor with limited tag set

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor

I need to configure JavaScript Rich Text Editor to operate only with a limited(strictly restricted) tag set:

```
b, i, pre, a, (\n == <br>) + Emoji
```

I found the following [Rich Text Editor](https://github.com/tovic/rich-text-editor) and configured for example to not use the `p` tag:

```
var editor = new RTE(document.querySelector('textarea'), {
        tags: [
            'a',
            'i',
            'pre',
            'br',
            'b'
        ],
```

but when I use it and switch to html(source) mode - it shows me the output with `p` tag, something like this:

```
<p>qwer</p>
```

Could you please tell me how to restrict the editor in order to produce only predefined(mentioned above) tag set or recommend another editor that will allow it?

Comment: `b, i, and pre` should be avoided moving forward in HTML 3. Instead, you should use CSS

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use only this exact tag set

Comment: In the doc it says "Note: All block tags are not allowed except <p> tags without attributes.". So maybe you cannot avoid <p> with the editor and should sanitize it later instead

Comment: Is it possible to configure this or another RTE to use `<p>` tag only as the owner container and al inner new lines interpret with `<br/>`?